# Create a Search records form through Bootstrap Modals PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm building a form within a Boostrap Modal, it has 3 `INPUT` fields and a `Submit` button for each row. Each `Submit` is `POST` onto another page. What I then want to do is use the variables to return data into a table which will show all the results for that particular search ie Postcode, StreetName. Within the table I have a `SUBMIT` button which will return the output into my main form on the main page.

The section I'm struggling with is to get the variable from the `INPUT` (from my modal, which I'm using on jobdetailssearch.php) to `POST` onto the search page (search.php). Once this is return then I'm going to show all the results in the form on my jobdetails page (jobdetails.php)

This below is my code for the 3 pages.

jobdetailssearch.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Search Projects</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">    
<form class="modal-form" id="searchform" name="searchform" action="includes/search.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" name="searchprojno" id="searchprojno" placeholder="Enter Project Number">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitsearchprojno" name="submitsearchprojno" >Search &nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" name="searchaddress" id="searchaddress" placeholder="Enter Address">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitsearchadd" name="submitsearchadd" >Search &nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postcode</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" name="searchpostcode" id="searchpostcode" placeholder="Enter Postcode">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitsearchpc" name="submitsearchpc" >Search &nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="100px"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Address</th>                                                                   
                            <th width="50px"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100px"></td>
                            <td width="50px"><a href="#" class="btn default btn-xs blue-stripe">Select Address</a></td>
                        </tr>                                                                   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer right">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
        <!--<button type="submit" class="btn blue">Select</button>-->
    </div>
</form>
    </div>
```

search.php

```
<?php
 require '../core/cnn.php';
if(isset($_POST['submitsearchprojno'])) {
    $searchprojno = $_POST["searchprojno"];
}
if(isset($_POST['submitsearchadd'])) {
    $searchaddress = $_POST["searchaddress"];
}
if(isset($_POST['submitsearchpc'])) {
    $searchpostcode = $_POST["searchpostcode"];
}
$searchpostcode = mysql_real_escape_string($searchpostcode);
$searchaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($searchaddress);
$searchprojno = mysql_real_escape_string($searchprojno);

$searchrs = mysql_query("SELECT ProjectNo, CONCAT(COALESCE(HouseNoName, ''), ' ', COALESCE(StreetName, ''), ' ', 
                            COALESCE(TownOrCity, ''), ' ', COALESCE(Postcode, '')) AS Display,
                            PropID, AreaID, AWGMember, Householder, HouseNoName, StreetName, TownOrCity,
                            Postcode, ContactTelephone, AlternatePhone, Email, PropertyTenure, PropertyNotes
                        FROM prop_property
                        WHERE IsActive = 1
                            AND (Postcode = '".$searchpostcode."'
                                OR StreetName = '".$searchaddress."'
                                OR ProjectNo = '".$searchprojno."')
                        ") or die(mysql_error());
$checkrs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prop_property WHERE IsActive = 0");
    if(!mysql_num_rows($checkrs) > 0) { 
        echo '<td> No record found!</td><td></td>'; 
    }
        else {
            while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($searchrs)) {
            echo '
            <td>'.$results['Display'].'</td>
            <td>
                <form action="jobdetails.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="searchhouse" value=" '.$results['HouseNoName'].'" >
                <input type="hidden" name="searchstreet" value=" '.$results['StreetName'].'" >
                <input type="hidden" name="searchtown" value=" '.$results['TownOrCity'].'" >
                <input type="hidden" name="searchpostcode" value=" '.$results['Postcode'].'" >
                <input type="hidden" name="searchpropid" value=" '.$results['PropID'].'" >
                <input type="hidden" name="searchprojectno" value=" '.$results['ProjectNo'].'" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn default btn-xs blue-stripe" name="viewsearch">View Address</button>
            </form>
        </td>';
    }
}
    ?>
```

The modal opens fine and shows the form in the way I want. What's the best way I should go about this to input the search criteria and show the results in a table for me to select and pull on to my main form on jobdetails.php (I've not included this as it's too big and not sure its needed to be seen)?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I understood your issue, you have your form in a modal view of bootstrap and you want send the data in the form to another page, process the search and then return the data that you find to the same modal and put it into the < tables>  that's your issue?

Well, if that is. Look I think the easier way to do this is using jquery, and change the input submit for a input button, because I don't remember very well but when you send a submit inside the modal, the modal it's closed. That's true? if that the problem change the submit for a button. Then you have to create a function .click() to the button to catch the event click, with the .serialize() (*if you want to check that you really are recieving the data you can make a die(var_dump($_POST)); in the php and check it in the console with firebug or something like that.*) you get the data of your < form> and then you have to send it with a .post() to the other file, in the php you recive the data and When you recive the response you can put it into the table with .html().

So the code that I'm thinking should look like this, uou can change it to make it how you need it, but this can be the base:

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#yourButtonID").click(function(){
          data = $("#yourFormID").serialize();
          $.post("yourPHPfileToSearch.php",data,function(dataReturn)){
                $("#yourTableID").html(dataReturn);
          });
    });

});
```

Let me know if you need more helpe. Regards. Have a nice day.